# ASP.NET Core Web API w/Swagger - How can I deserialize "oneOf" types from request body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, deserialization

I'm working with ASP.NET core minimal web API, dotnet6.

Swashbuckle allows me to define the structure of my endpoints as `oneOf` by using a base class and creating subclasses: `builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.UseOneOfForPolymorphism());`

...and these are are the classes I defined:

```
public abstract class Shape { }
public class Circle : Shape { public double Radius { get; set; } }
public class Square : Shape { public double Length { get; set; } }
```

As far as the generated swagger schema, this works exactly as intended:

```
"/oneOfTest": {
      "post": {
           ...
              "schema": {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Circle"
                  },
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Square"
                  }
                ]
```

But when I call the method, I get an exception, because the service tries to deserialize the data as `Shape` and not one of its subclasses:

`System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Shape'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.`

**How can I get my service to deserialize the incoming JSON as the appropriate subclass rather than the base class?**

Note: for this simple example I made the whole body `oneOf`, but I'd like the deserialization solution to be applicable to parts of a larger object as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: @KirkLarkin , I noted that as a recommended solution for .NET 7

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as @KirkLarkin notes, .NET 7 adds a solution for this problem, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0). My solution applies to .NET 6.

I can define a custom converter to handle the deserialization of specific type (`Shape`) by inheriting from `JsonConverter<Shape>`. Here is my implementation:

```
public class ShapeConverter : JsonConverter<Shape>
{
    public override Shape? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var shapeObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(ref reader, options)!;
        if (shapeObj.ContainsKey(nameof(Circle.Radius)))
        {
            return shapeObj.Deserialize<Circle>(options);
        }
        else if (shapeObj.ContainsKey(nameof(Square.Length)))
        {
            return shapeObj.Deserialize<Square>(options);
        }
        else throw new Exception("Discriminator could not be identified");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Shape value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm first deserializing to a generic `JsonObject`, then using specific discriminators to determine which subclass I'm looking at. I'm using the built-in deserialization methods rather than trying to work directly with the `Utf8JsonReader`.)

Then, I can register that converter with my WebApplicationBuilder:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o =>
{
    o.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new ShapeConverter());
});
```

Now, when my handler receives a request, the instance will be deserialized into the correct subclass.